How to install missing python modules on distroless Image?
I am trying to install some missing modules on a python distroless image however I am getting below error
 => ERROR [3/7] RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip                                                                                    0.3s
------
 > [3/7] RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip:
0.253 runc run failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory

Looks like the distroless image does not have shell (/bin/sh).
Below is the Dockerfile. Is there an alternate way to install the required modules? Could you please advise.
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian12:nonroot

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org requests simplejson python-json-logger



To give you an idea, if I were to install Python packages in a distroless image, I’ll use a multi-stage build. I’ll first install the packages in a regular Python image, then copy them to the distroless image. Something like this:
# Use a regular Python image to install packages
FROM python:3.12-slim as builder

# Install the required packages
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org requests simplejson python-json-logger

# Switch to the distroless image
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian12:nonroot

# Copy the installed packages
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin

This approach would get around the missing shell issue in distroless images by doing the package installation in a regular Python environment first.
I hope this helps.

Thank you for your response. Looks like this is the right way to install packages on distroless version. I have created the image with the above steps. Only issue is that I am getting below error when I try to start the container "python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.12.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" . Looks like I need to copy some additional stuff.

You might need to copy the necessary shared libraries from the builder stage to the distroless stage. The shared libraries are typically located in /usr/local/lib and possibly in other directories as well.
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.
The /usr/local/lib directory is copied to ensure all necessary libraries, including libpython3.12.so.1.0 are included. The /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory is copied to include any additional shared libraries that might be required.
Give this a shot.

Adding the above copy command fixed the issue. Thank you very much. Just one last question. As we want to use distroless for security reasons, Is python:3.12-slim is official and safe image?

Yes, python:3.12-slim is an official image provided by the Python Software Foundation. It is a lightweight version, which helps to minimize the attack surface. However, to maintain security, there are best practices to follow, e.g regularly update the image, monitor security notices, and use security scanning tools like Docker Hub's scanner or Snyk to identify and address vulnerabilities. Following these ensures the image remains a secure choice for your applications. You can also verify its official status here - https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags?page=&page_size=&ordering=&name=3.12-slim

I had to insert ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages as well
